# Div Resizing on Hover CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two divs side by side with an iframe.  When I hover over the div on the left, I want the iframe on the right to resize to 50% width.  The div on the left would then be resized to be 50%.  I would prefer a pure CSS approach to this.

```css
.answer6{
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}

.mpi-options-all2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 75px;
  right: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;  
    opacity:0.8;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
 text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    height: 505px;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: right 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: right 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: right 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: right 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.left-right{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 525px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left-right:hover .mpi-options-all2{
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="answer6">
  <iframe src="https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" width="75%" height="500" align="right"></iframe>
  <div class ="left-right">
    <div class="mpi-options-all2">
    <h2><center>Description:</center></h2>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Should your description div still be moving out of under iframe?

Comment: @Justinas - That is how I want it.  It should still be hidden underneath.  I intend on making a small arrow or little question mark box for a user to hover over.  Almost like a pulsing button or something like that.

Comment: When you hover on the left div the iframe on the right should resize to 50% width and then the div you just hovered over should also resize to 50% ? is this correct ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak - That is correct.

Comment: and by default the left div is 100% width and the iframe is 0% width ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak - I think that makes sense.  I would be fine seeing the entire width of the div on the left if a user hovers over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I understood about the problem, here is a solution to see if it is correct.

```
<div class="answer6">
      <div class ="left-right">
        <div class="mpi-options-all2">
        <h2><center>Description:</center></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <iframe src="https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" height="500" align="right"></iframe>      
    </div>
```

---

```
.answer6{
    width: 100%;
}
.mpi-options-all2 h2{
  display: none;
}

.mpi-options-all2 {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 75px;
  /*right: 75px;*/
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;  
    opacity:0.8;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*right: -100%;*/
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    height: 505px;
    /*z-index: 2;*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.left-right{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 525px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 2%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

iframe{
  margin:0;
  width: 97.7%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  float:right;
}
.left-right:hover .mpi-options-all2 h2{
  display: block;
}

.left-right:hover{
    width: 49.7%;
}

.left-right:hover ~ iframe{
    width: 50%;
}
```

---

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROEogj

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  It went beyond my expectations.  Now I just need to put a little arrow there so users know to hover over it.  Thanks!